# Overriding rxjs pairwise behaviour

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using NgRx in my app, and I'm trying to build some kind of a caching so that my requests would not trigger unless the request parameters have changed.

I decided it could be the best scenario to build the cache in my effects. So I did the following:

```
getUsers$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromActions.getUsers),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectRequestParams).pipe(
      startWith({}),
      pairwise(),
    )),
    mergeMap(([_, params]) => iif(() => JSON.stringify(params[0]) === JSON.stringify(params[1]),
      EMPTY,
      this.service.getUsers(params[1] ?? params[0]).pipe(
        map(result => fromActions.getUsersSuccess({ pagedUser: result })),
        catchError(_ => of(fromActions.getUsersFailed())),
      ),
   )),
));
```

Now, the problem is that my `pairwise` is emitting the last 2 values available in the store, and not the last 2 values that were actually used in the previous emission. So for example, consider the following steps:

1. Page loads with `pageSize` 20 in the params
2. User sets the `pageSize` to 500
3. User navigates to another page
4. User goes back to the previous page

In this scenario, the request will still be sent, because the `pairwise` is returning `{ pageSize: 20 }` and `{ pageSize: 500 }`. However, what I expect should look like `{ pageSize: 500 }` and `{ pageSize: 500 }`

Comment: `withLatestFrom` is already caching and there seems to be no change in request params after it was set to 500. So it's correct in your case, previous is indeed 20.

Comment: @dallows but the problem is that the request is being sent when navigating back to the page. I want to avoid that.

Comment: I'm afraid in your case you have to update RequestParams after `getUsers` call, to make sure pairwise returns correct value. Or use some helper property

Comment: @dallows can you please suggest a solution with a helper property?

Comment: Do you dispatch `getUsers` action from component's `ngOnInit`? Don't you just use selector there and dispatch it only when `pageSize` was changed?

Comment: check out `distinctUntilChanged`